# How to develop applications with Docker which are in separate repositories

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The stack consists of a few applications/microservices need to be connected to run locally in development, and each is within its own repository

E.g. frontend, db, api

If each app has its own Dockerfile, and docker-compose.yml that list the required services to run that one application, what practices are recommended for development of the whole stack?

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what we do at work.

Front end angular running on Apache (prod) or node (dev)
All bog standard request are handled normally, all request to api container have /imanapicall in the url and are proxied to the api container based on the fact that the url contains /imanapicall
This is standard practice. Fe container is stateless.

We have node running the api, it is stateless and simply requests data from db and sends it back to front end

We have node running restify but express more popular

Then most people use mongodb but we use some weird db stuff

Important thing is to expose ports between containers, make sure firewalls aren't being a pain. For dev purposes you prob wanna expose ports for all containers to host also so u can debug more easily by for example hitting an express endpoint directly to make sure it's giving me wot I want

Ps statelessness important to support scaling, so I can introduce a load balancer and not worry which server it hits. Only db container holds state

FURTHER TO YOUR COMMENT ...

Each tier (db, api, etc) has its own git repo.
Each git repo has an automated Jenkins job that does a build (on a push to the repo) and on success pushes a new docker image.

We then have another git repo that is responsible for pulling it all together. this repo basically consist of a docker compose file to pull all the relevant containers and run them.
job done.

this gives a simple overview. if you have any more detailed questions feel free to ask.

FINE DETAIL ...

During development of the db tier no difficulties arise.

However, during development of the api tier, for example, this tier is dependent on the db tier, so a docker container for the db tier will need to be running when developing the api tier. Can use compose for this also.

When developing front end tier, this relies on both db and api tiers.
Its best to use a generic solution during development that allows all containers to be stood up in their latest docker image state and ignore those that are irrelevant for current purposes.

For example,

When developing front end, bring up all 3 containers from the latest images. Ignore the front end container and use your front end development environment as usual. Point the front end development environment to the api container. Hope this makes sense.

Ignoring the containers that are irrelevant for the development of the tier you are working on means you can use a common approach when brining up docker containers for all tiers without having a specific solution for each.

hope this makes sense, not the easiest thing to explain!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really explain how you have it laid out. do you have one compose file that boots them all? use service discovery locally? More details would be helpful.

Comment: added more info to answer